# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Permission denied (13)

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

Good day!

Im trying to make my phpmailer work in my shared hosting `(freehostia.com)` and I always get this error. The username and password of my gmail is correct, and the rest of the settings is like this:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->Host       = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'mymail@gmail.com'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'mypassword'; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port       = 587; // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('mymail@gmail.com', 'ASAPHOT Administrator'); // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('sorianorobertc@gmail.com'); // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('mymail@gmail.com', 'ASAPHOT Administrator');

$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'it works';
$mail->Body    = 'it works';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

openssl is uncommented in the `php.ini` also. Am I missing something here? Thank you.

Complete error message:

```
Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Permission denied (13)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page)

Comment: That question is not a duplicate of this one.

Comment: Maybe you don't have a firewall on your machine and php can't create sockets.

Comment: @gtzinos Does phpmailer require a firewall? (Innocent question.)

Answer (score 26):

Let's get to the answer first of all! Try with the following command:

```
$ getsebool httpd_can_sendmail
```

if it shows: `httpd_can_sendmail --> off`

switch it on with this:

```
$ sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1
```

then try sending the email again.

This solution comes from this great [page](https://gistpages.com/posts/phpmailer_smtp_error_failed_to_connect_to_server_permission_denied_13_fix).

As it was pointed out from this article, you may also need to try `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`. While for my CentOS 7 vm hosted by DigitalOcean, it's not necessary.

The problem I met was failing to send out emails from a Drupal website, with the SMTP Authentication Support module, which relies on PHPMailer underneath. And the SMTP server used was Google.

BTW, I had suspected it was OpenSSL certificate problem and did some test but no luck. So by setting the `$SMTPDebug` level to 2 from the PHPMailer source code, I was able to capture the "Permission denied (13)" error message.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, I wish I could upvote it more than once.

Answer (score 2):

This suggests that fopen wrappers or socket functions are disabled in your PHP installation. Not unusual in shared hosting. Running `phpinfo()` should tell you.

You can probably use `$mail->isMail();` and skip the auth to send via the ISP's mail server instead of SMTP, but beware of SPF issues.

Comment: you just helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the free hosting of freehostia blocks outcoming mails.

Answer (score 0):

Freehostia blocks the list below in the free plan. (Chocolate)

-mailer

-curl

-soap get

-xml get

Answer (score 0):

this is important for http

- getsebool httpd_can_sendmail is Off then turn On it
  sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1
- may need sudo 'setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1'
- disable_function = ...... delete exec for exec() in php.ini

Answer (score -2):

```
use this
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port
```

if this not working than try bellow for php code.

mail($to,$subject,$message);

Comment: try this $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;        // 1 to enables SMTP debug (for testing), 0 to disable debug (for production)

Comment: Hi dear, your phpmailer class file is not a correct code. so please find correct class.phpmailer.php